# Removing 2 minutes from NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to be able to remove two minutes from an existing NSDate. This is how the code looks like:

```
timeForLocalPush = defaults.objectForKey("timeForLocalPush") as! String



//Add the extra zero so the dateformatter :ss will match, remove 2 minutes from the time and set the fire date to it!
timeForLocalPush = timeForLocalPush + " " + self.timePicked + ":00"

print(timeForLocalPush)

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let newDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Minute, value: -2, toDate: formatter.dateFromString(timeForLocalPush)!, options: [])

print(newDate!)
```

The two prints are giving me this:

```
2016-08-30 17:30:00
2016-08-30 15:28:00 +0000
```

It is removing two minutes but also two hours?

Comment: print dateFromString(timeForLocalPush)! before convert and see is it same like `print(timeForLocalPush)`

Comment: Its giving me another value. But why? i am not changing it anywhere... @MikeAlter

Comment: The string shows the date in your local time zone. NSDate shows the date in UTC.

Comment: Spank you, i added   formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) and it worked fine @MartinR

Comment: @TimoCengiz: That is actually the wrong fix, and would mean that the notification is delivered at 17:28 GMT, not 17:28 your time.

Comment: @MartinR can you please show what is right way to do this , mean that the notification is delivered at 17:28 GMT, not 17:28 your time ?

Comment: yes, how is the correct way of doing it then? @MartinR¨

Comment: @TimoCengiz: `newDate` is 17:28 in your time zone, it is just *printed* as UTC time. To see the value of `newDate` in your time zone, convert it back to a string with the date formatter: `print(formatter.stringFromDate(newDate!))`.